# get total count and created after count for same table in one query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have team and teams has many teams_users.
I want to get the count of total users of team & users created for team in last 30 days.

I have tried below approach but getting same number for both

```
Team.joins(:teams_users)
    .select("teams.id, COUNT(teams_users.id) as total_users, COUNT( CASE WHEN teams_users.created_at > #{Date.today -
30.days} THEN 1 END) AS joined_in_month")
    .group('teams.id').map(&:attributes)
```

output

```
[640] {
                 "id" => 688,
        "total_users" => 3,
    "joined_in_month" => 3
},
[641] {
                 "id" => 689,
        "total_users" => 2,
    "joined_in_month" => 2
},
[642] {
                 "id" => 690,
        "total_users" => 1,
    "joined_in_month" => 1
}
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the SQL

Comment: Sounds like something you would use a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) for  on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` on the second part. Assuming there are single row for each `user` per `team` in `teams_users` then you should have it with a query like:

```
SELECT
   tu.teams_id,
   COUNT(0) AS total_users,
   SUM(tu.created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AS joined_in_month
FROM teams_users tu
GROUP BY tu.teams_id
;
```